# cmake based bitbake recipe : sysroot missing?

Tags: c++, cmake, bitbake, openembedded

I feel like I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. I created a recipe based on a cmake project. Compiling the project using the toolchain yocto created is as simple as running *cmake* then *make* but it fails to compile using a recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Opendnp3 is the de facto reference implementation of IEEE-1815 (DNP3)"
DESCRIPTION = "Opendnp3 is a portable, scalable, and rigorously tested implementation of the DNP3 (www.dnp.org) protocol stack written in C++11. The library is designed for high-performance applications like many concurrent TCP sessions or huge device simulations. It also embeds very nicely on Linux."
HOMEPAGE = "https://www.automatak.com/opendnp3"
SECTION = "libs"
DEPENDS = "asio"
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://NOTICE;md5=9788d3abe6c9401d72fdb3717de33e6a"
SRCREV = "e00ff31b837821064e5208c15866a9d46f8777b1"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/automatak/dnp3;branch=2.0.x"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
inherit cmake
EXTRA_OECMAKE += ""
```

Problem is I think that the CXXFLAGS used for g++ don't appear to be consistent with the CXXFLAGS defined by the toolchain's environment. Mainly *--sysroot* is missing and g++ fails to find standard c++ headers (ex: *cstdint*).

I partially fixed the issue by overriding do_configure from cmake.bbclas simply by removing *-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${WORKDIR}/toolchain.cmake*. As a matter of fact CXXFLAGS are defined by toolchain.cmake as:

```
 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a8  --sysroot=/home/star/moxa-build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/dnp3/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/star/moxa-build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/dnp3/2.2.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/dnp3/2.2.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/star/moxa-build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/dnp3/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/star/moxa-build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/dnp3/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot=  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a8  --sysroot=/home/star/moxa-build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/dnp3/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot
```

So sysroot is defined (twice actually) as:

```
/home/star/moxa-build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/dnp3/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot
```

but doesn't end up in the Makefile generated by cmake so I guess that something in [toolchain.cmake](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Ag-ilTJ9VVdTRVUTFEcnNJSTA) makes the project's cmake configuration go south.

Turns out it was a cmake issue with the project itself. There was a merry mix-up between C and CXX flags in one of the included .cmake configuration file. I'll submit a pull request to the maintainer. CXXFLAGS being handled differently between the SDK (included directly in th CXX command) and by bitbake explained why it worked with the SDK (still not quite sure why it worked without [toolchain.cmake](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Ag-ilTJ9VVdTRVUTFEcnNJSTA) though).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the error when you bitbake the recipe? Have you tried without the EXTRA_OECMAKE line?

Comment: Sure. The recipe compile log is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Ag-ilTJ9VVaFhyZTVLMGVIdHc). Same results when removing the line _EXTRA_OECMAKE += ""_

Comment: I'd check the error "fatal error: cstdint: No such file or directory". Some suggests that you need to add gcc-multilib to your image. https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-September/021760.html

Comment: Thanks. It was certainly worth a try but installing gcc-multilib on the Ubuntu build host didn't fix it. It does work using yocto's toolchain and standard cmake build flow so I don't think it's related to the build host but more likely to the recipe. Could it be that bitbake uses its own cmake implementation?

Comment: I probably didn't explain correctly. I meant add `gcc-multilib` to the yocto image.

Comment: Actually that's what I understood but based on the [hyperlink](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-September/021760.html) I was under the impressions that installating gcc-multilib on the host was the suggested fix. I added  _require recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-multilib-config.inc_ in the configuration (_local.conf_) but it appears that it was alreary include through _gcc-configure-common.inc_ and resulted in the same error. Was that what you meant by adding _gcc-multilib_ to my image (I don't believe there's a gcc-multilib recipe)?

Comment: Missing things like atomic, string, cstdint happened to me and it was because my CmakeLists.txt file had CXX flags being set incorrectly.  It was setting flags without assuming there were existing flags, just overwriting them.   Yocto's CXX flags and environment therefore weren't being inherited correctly.  Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72621749/yocto-bitbake-fails-to-find-wrapper-headers-include-next-stind-h-no-such-file/72747415#72747415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--sysroot` is missing from `CXXFLAGS` because yocto stuffs it in the `CXX` variable itself. Note that alongside the `sysroots` directory yocto will have an `environment-setup-XXX` file which you should source. That's where all the sysroot stuff comes from.

Comment: Thanks. When I source the script provided with the yocto toolchain (_environment-setup-cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi_ in this case) _CXX_ is defined as _arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a8 --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.3/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi_ and calling the host's _cmake_ and _make_ goes  smootly with that environment. I would assume that the same environment is used through the recipe but that the implementation of cmake and make could differ.

Comment: @Louis: I wouldn't know which "implementation of cmake"  you're referring to. AFAIK there's no separate `make` under `/opt/poky`. And why would there need to be one?

Comment: I was refering to Ross Burton's post (see below). My understanding is that bitbake doesn't use cmake as installed on the host

Comment: @Louis: Could well be. I've been using Yocto for a week, so I recently had to figure out these things as well. And my distinct impression is that they really like to reinvent the wheel, but documenting the reinvented wheels is not so much a priority.

Comment: Same here (been using Yocto for a week although I followed a traning 2 years ago)! but while checking which cmake I use after sourcing the script I found out that I was actually using Yocto's cmake.